# Odd construction of disjoint (topological) union

Tags: general-topology

Let $X_1\subset X_2$ be a (strictly) nested subsets and equip each $X_i$ with a topology $\tau^i$ such that $X_1$ is closed in $(X_2,\tau^2)$ and $\tau_2|_{X_1}\subseteq \tau_1$.  Then why is the topology generated by $\tau^1\cup \tau^2$ equal to the disjoint union topology on $(X_1,\tau^1)\sqcup (X_2-X_1,\tau^2|_{X_2-X_1}
)$?

Comment: The underlying set of  $(X_1,\tau^1)\sqcup (X_2,\tau^2)$ is someting like $X_1\times\{1\}\cup X_2\times \{2\}$. Then with $\tau^1\cup \tau^2$, do you mean $(\tau 1\times\{1\})\cup (\tau^2\times\{2\})$? In tht case, the claim is trivial, isn't it?

Comment: It isn’t, unless $\tau^1$ contains the restriction of $\tau^2$ to $X_1$, so that the topology generated by $\tau^1\cup\tau^2$ on $X_1$ is just $\tau^1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  Right, I forgot to write down that assumption.  But how to show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\tau$ be the generated topology. Suppose that $U\subseteq X_1$ and $U\in\tau$. Then $U$ is a union of sets of the form $V\cap W$, where $V\in\tau^1$ and $W\in\tau^2$. Such a set $V\cap W$ is a subset of $X_1$, so $V\cap W=V\cap(W\cap X_1)$, and by hypothesis $W\cap X_1\in\tau^1$, so in fact $V\cap W\in\tau^1$. Thus, $U$ is a union of members of $\tau^1$ and is therefore itself in $\tau^1$. In other words, the subspace topology that $X_1$ inherits from $\tau$ is just its original topology $\tau^1$.

It’s clear that the subspace topology that $X_2\setminus X_1$ inherits from $\tau$ is just its subspace topology from $\tau^2$.

Finally, $X_2\setminus X_1\in\tau^2$, so $X_2\setminus X_1\in\tau$, and $X_1$ is therefore a closed set in $\langle X_2,\tau\rangle$. On the other hand, $X_1\in\tau^1$, $X_2\in\tau^2$, so $X_1=X_1\cap X_2\in\tau$, i.e., $X_1$ is an open set in $\langle X_2,\tau\rangle$. Thus, $X_1$ is clopen in $\langle X_2,\tau\rangle$, which is therefore the discrete union of $X_1$ and $X_2\setminus X_1$ with their subspace topologies, which, as we’ve already seen, are in fact their original topologies.